# cannot convert from "initializer list"

Tags: c++, arrays, list, vector, initialization

I am new and have an issue in C++. I am creating 3D coordinates, (x, y and z for each corner of a face, then 6 faces) and receive many errors. Here is my code:

```
#include <vector>
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> xyzCoords = {
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
    };

    int x1 = 0;
    int y1 = 1;
    int z1 = 2;
    int x2 = 3;
    int y2 = 4;
    int z2 = 5;

    xyzCoords = {
    { x1, y1, z1, x2, y1, z1, x2, y1, z2, x1, y1, z2 },
    { x1, y2, z1, x2, y2, z1, x2, y2, z2, x1, y2, z2 },
    { x1, y2, z1, x1, y1, z1, x1, y1, z2, x1, y2, z2 },
    { x2, y2, z1, x2, y1, z1, x2, y1, z2, x2, y2, z2 },
    { x1, y2, z2, x1, y1, z2, x2, y1, z2, x2, y2, z2 },
    { x1, y2, z1, x1, y1, z1, x2, y1, z1, x2, y2, z1 }
    };
    return 0;
}
```

This the code where the problem occurs. You can see I'm defining `xyzCoords` as a vector. I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do it. I also don't want to be defining `xyz123` separately. What is the best way to achieve this? Shall I use a list, array or vector? Please write the code for how to do this. Thanks!
Errors:

> E0289:    no instance of constructor "std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::vector [with _Ty=int, _Alloc=std::allocator]" matches the argument list
>
> E0349:    no operator "=" matches these operands
>
> C2440:    'initializing': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'std::vector>'
>
> C2679:    binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'initializer list' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Comment: Removed the nested `{}`s.

Comment: What is `<vectors>`?

Comment: @juanchopanza, you forgot your tongue-in-cheek emoji :)

Comment: You are trying to assign a 2-dimensional `int[6][12]` array, but your vector only supports 1-dimension. You probably want to define a `struct` containing the `x,y,z` coordinates, and then construct the vector using a 1-dimensional array of structs.  If you really want a 2-dimensional vector, you have to define your vector as holding another vector, which in turn holds the coordinates

Comment: @juanchopanza Oops didn't see that - it's because I copied and pasted the main script then typed the #include

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your initialization is unmatch with the type you had declared. You declare a 1D array whereas your initialization is 2D array.

```
std::vector<int> xyzCoords = {
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
};
```

It should be :

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> xyzCoords = {
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
};
```

You mentioned about `xyz` coordinate, so why don't you make a class specially used for coordinate, for instance :

```
struct Point {
   int x, y, z;
};
```

Anyway, I don't recommend you to use naive approach for this problem because it will be a matrix-operation-intensive computation. You should use [BLAS](http://www.netlib.org/blas/)/[LAPACK](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) library or it's wrapper like [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org) or [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net). They are surely far faster.

Comment: Thanks for this! I'm glad that you explained how you could get around the problem I had. Because it is slow, I think I will just change my code slightly.

Comment: I'm confused, which problem are you recommending blas/lapack for? OP just wanted an array of cube vertices as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you should restructure your code to something like this, for visibility and better understanding:

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    struct Corner
    {
        int x;
        int y;
        int z;
        Corner(int x, int y, int z) :
            x(x), y(y), z(z) {}
    };

    struct Face
    {
        Corner c1;
        Corner c2;
        Corner c3;
        Corner c4;
        Face(Corner c1, Corner c2, Corner c3, Corner c4) :
            c1(c1), c2(c2), c3(c3), c4(c4) {}
    };

    Corner c1(0, 1, 2);
    Corner c2(3, 4, 5);
    Face f1(c1, c2, c1, c2);

    std::vector<Face> faces = { f1, f1, f1, f1, f1, f1 };

    return 0;
}
```

This creates array of 6 faces with coordinates of the corners (x1,y1,z1) (x2,y2,z2) (x1,y1,z1) (x2,y2,z2)

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <vector>

struct Vertex {
    float x_; // can change these to int
    float y_;
    float z_;
    Vertex() : x_(0), y_(0), z_(0) {}
    Vertex( float x, float y, float z ) : x_(x), y_(y), z_(z) {}
    explicit Vertex( float val ) : x_(val), y_(val), z_(val) {}
};

struct Face {
    Vertex v0_;
    Vertex v1_;
    Vertex v2_;
    Vertex v3_;

    Face() : 
    v0_(Vertex()), 
    v1_(Vertex()),
    v2_(Vertex()), 
    v3_(Vertex()) {
    }

    Face( Vertex v0, Vertex v1, Vertex v2, Vertex v3 ) :
    v0_(v0),
    v1_(v1),
    v2_(v2),
    v3_(v3) {
    }          
};

int main() {
    std::vector<Face> faces;

    // Not exact values the OP is looking for,
    // just a quick way to populate the vector of faces
    // for demonstration purposes of the usefulness of structs & classes.
    for ( unsigned n = 1; n <= 6; n++ ) {
        faces.push_back( Face( Vertex(n), Vertex(n+1), Vertex(n+2), Vertex(n+3) ) );
    }        

    return 0;
}
```